# watching route with routeParams not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a $watch setup that is monitoring the UI router path and triggering certain events if the location.path is equal to specific routes. this works for all routes that do not have a parameter in them. does anyone know a workaround?

here is the code

```
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $location.path();
      }, function(){

            if(
                $location.path() == '/dashboard' ||
                $location.path() == '/mySettings' ||
                $location.path() == '/myAccount' ||
                $location.path() == '/new_company' ||
                $location.path() == '/company/view/:id' ||
                $location.path() == '/companies/view/all' ||
                $location.path() == '/agreement/new' ||
                $location.path() == '/agreement/:id/map' ||
                $location.path() == '/invitation/new' ||
                $location.path() == '/inbox'
              ) {

                  sessionWatcher();

              } else {

                var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#wrapper' ) );
                myEl.addClass('authPage');

                var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#page-content-wrapper' ) );
                myEl.addClass('fullScreen');

                checkSessionFalse();

              }

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok worked it out.

If anyone else ever has this issue, I recommend using the indexOff method which is similar to the jquery contains method.

```
$location.path().indexOf('thevaluetocheck') > -1
```

find more info on the following link

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location